# Eevee: Vertical line running through reflective/shiny hair particles

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, hair

I have an issue with Eevee when trying to view and render hair particles. I want to use shiny hair, but whenever the hair material I'm using is reflective or metallic, a vertical line appears in the camera view, user perspective view, and render view. When I move to orthographic view, it disappears. If I move the object around, the vertical line is still visible but remains in the same place (at the world origin point). No matter what I change in the hair particle or hair material settings, I can't get this vertical line to go away. There's nothing in the scene or the HDRI that would be causing such a reflection (it appears regardless of what else is in the scene). Does anyone know what might be causing it?

Here is the .blend file: https://pasteall.org/media/5/8/585db6c7efdc0f210599cf27189b99b6.blend

[image: eevee1]

[[image: eevee23][image: eevee3]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Sorry, the first time I wasn't aware of how to include the .blend file, so I deleted the original question and resubmitted it.

Comment: Your blend file is missing the environment map, which is essential to diagnose the issue

Comment: Sorry about that. It appears regardless of which environment map is used. Here's the .blend file with everything packed: https://pasteall.org/media/0/9/091c3b434b2c4dd5bec06aae9c7d46d0.blend

Comment: The solution is to enable *Screen Space Reflections* in EEVEE.